# Calling Bootstrap methods via Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I need to call the hide-method on a Collapsable via Angular. So what I tried was to retrieve the Element via ViewChild and execute the hide() method on element.nativeElement.hide(). However, it gives me an error that the hide() method does not exist, although the returned element is correct (checked via console.log).

Here are the code-snippets:

Template:

```html
<div *ngIf="consultation.status == 'open'">
    <p>
        <input type="button" [value]="editButtonText" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-bs-toggle="collapse" 
            data-bs-target=".multi-collapse" aria-expanded="false" 
            attr.aria-controls="waiterCommentBox{{ consultation.consultationId }} saveRequestButton{{ consultation.consultationId }}" 
            (click)="toggleRequestEditMode()">
        <input type="button" value="Save Changes" id="saveRequestButton{{ consultation.consultationId}}" 
            class="btn btn-outline-success collapse multi-collapse collapse-horizontal" (click)="saveRequest()">
    </p>
    
    <div class="collapse multi-collapse" #waiterCommentBox id="waiterCommentBox{{ consultation.consultationId }}">
        <div class="card card-body">
            <textarea name="waiterComment" id="waiterComment" [(ngModel)]="consultation.waiterComment" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Component Code:

```
import { Component, Input, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { ConsultationRequest } from "../model/consultation-request";
import { ConsultationRequestsService } from "../services/consultation-requests.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'consultation-state',
    templateUrl: './consultation-state.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ './consultation-state.component.scss' ]
})
export class ConsultationStateComponent {

    @Input('counsultation') consultation = new ConsultationRequest();
    @ViewChild('waiterCommentBox') waiterCommentBox: any;
    editMode = false;
    editButtonText = "Edit Request";


    constructor(private consultationService: ConsultationRequestsService) {}

    toggleRequestEditMode() {
        this.editMode = !this.editMode;
        this.editButtonText = this.editMode ? "Cancel Editing" : "Edit Request";
    }

    saveRequest() {
        this.consultationService.updateConsultationRequest(
                this.consultation.consultationId.toString(), { status: "closed", waiterComment: this.consultation.waiterComment } )
                .subscribe(result => {
                    this.consultation.status = "closed";
                    this.waiterCommentBox.nativeElement.hide();
                });
    }
}
```

Error-Message in Console:

> ERROR TypeError: this.waiterCommentBox.nativeElement.hide is not a function
> at SafeSubscriber._next (consultation-state.component.ts:31:66)
> at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183:1)
> at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122:1)
> at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72:1)
> at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49:1)
> at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35:1)
> at MapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49:1)
> at FilterSubscriber._next (filter.js:33:1)
> at FilterSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49:1)
> at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.js:70:1)

I tried retrieving the element by document.getElementById, but that won't even let me compile the TS code (property 'hide' does not exist on HTMLElement').

Bootstrap version: 5.1.3 - installed locally including JS

angluar.json

```
"scripts": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
```

package.json

```
"ajv": "^6.12.6",
"bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
"rxjs": "~6.6.0",
```

Angular 12.2.15

Comment: `.hide()` is a jQuery method, and, as the error indicates, not a method on an `HTMLElement`. Either wrap it in jQuery (i.e., `$(...).hide()`) or use an HTML attribute (`.hidden = true`) or CSS (`.style.display = "none"`).

Comment: OK, I thought BS5 dropped jQuery. The description on the BS-site (v5.1) provides those methods. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/collapse/#methods The reason I need this mothod is, because somewhere else I check for the show-class, which does not get removed by setting HTML-attributes.

Comment: Missed the Bootstrap version. You need to get the instance of the Collapse. Described on that site https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/javascript/#asynchronous-functions-and-transitions

Comment: Isn't that what #waiterBoxComment in the template + @ViewChild('waiterBoxComment') waiterBoxComment should do or am I missing something?

Comment: That doesn't get you a reference to the Bootstrap Collapse instance. You need to do something like `var collapse = bootstrap.Collapse.getInstance(this.waiterCommentBox.nativeElement)` to get that, then call `hide` on that. (I think; I haven't used Bootstrap since v3).

Answer (score 0):

`(this.waiterCommentBox.nativeElement as any).hide();`
Is the quick and dirty solution,
It's better to use the type of collapsible instead of "any", I just don't know the name of that type

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately the error remains: ERROR TypeError: this.waiterCommentBox.nativeElement.hide is not a function
    at SafeSubscriber._next (consultation-state.component.ts:31:66)

Comment: That won't work because `hide` is still not a method of an `HTMLElement`. You've just moved it to a run-time error, not a compile-time error.

Answer (score 0):

declare bootstrap below imports

```
declare const bootstrap: any;
@Component({ ... })
```

You need to get collapse instance to use hide method

```
@ViewChild('waiterCommentBox', { read: ElementRef }) waiterCommentBox: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;

const collapseInstance = bootstrap.Collapse.getInstance(this.waiterCommentBox.nativeElement);
if (collapseInstance) {
    collapseInstance.hide();
}
```